# Discord - Bot commands not working in "channel threads" feature

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot doesn't detect/respond to commands when executed in channel threads, how do I fix it?

[image]

When I search about this on Google, it thinks I'm asking for multithreaded programming.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(DEVELOPER_ROLE)
async def debug(ctx):
    print('my code')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Do you have any code related to the error?

Comment: I don't think it's printing any logs, i have logging set to `on_command_error`

Comment: Do you have any minimum, reproducible examples that you could show us? We cannot give you the answer without seeing something you have tried first. Do visit how-to-ask for further assistance. Have a good one :)

Comment: Hey, I don't have any idea about discord threads, it's a new feature and today I saw that my bot doesn't respond in threads. Otherwise everything else is working, i'm `processing commands` on `on_message`

Comment: You should read about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also  you should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I cannot provide an example since i don't know anything about this part, and google didn't gave me any results either. google thinks i'm asking for multithreaded programming

Comment: Can we know your `discord` package version, If I remember correctly threads are yet to be implemented (maybe v2.0.0+).

Comment: yes it shows `1.7.3`

Comment: @Arghadip, I talked to them in discord and found that it is indeed for v2.0. Currently [master](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Thread) has the code.

Comment: How to get version 2.0 on mac (i'm using brew) can you help me? And is V2.0 stable?

Comment: You can install it via pip by using `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py` and it is fairly stable yes. However there are some breaking changes listed here: https://gist.github.com/apple502j/f75b4f24652f04de85c7084ffd73ec58

Answer (score 0):

The PyPi version of discord.py is only updated to version `1.7.3`. However, discord.py only added support for threads in the `2.0` major update. To update to this version, do:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@master
```

Considering that there's many breaking changes that comes with the update, and that discord.py is no longer maintained, perhaps consider switching over to one of the popular forks to receive future bug fixes and new features.